# Lambda or API Gateway for consuming microservices in a microservices architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have a microservices architecture in my application, where I use AWS Lambda as a serverless function and API Gateway to expose APIs for my microservices. Currently, I need to consume one or more microservices from another microservice within my architecture.

1. Would it be more convenient to consume the Lambda function directly or use fetch to consume the endpoint exposed in API Gateway?
2. Considering factors such as efficiency, flexibility, security, and scalability, which would be the best option in this scenario?

It's worth noting that I have a web and mobile application, and the need to consume one or more services is to adapt them to the backend for frontend pattern.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWS architecture illustration that shows a valid pattern when building serverless apps. The app makes requests via API Gateway. That in return invokes AWS Lambda functions that invokes specific AWS Services. This should help answer your question.

[image]

By the way, the client in this example is a React app that works with the AWS Services shown in the illustration.